# Instalador MSI - customizando o instalador

Tags: visual-studio

Bom pessoal, primeiro preciso saber se é possível em um instalador MSI (utilizo o próprio 'setup project' que tem no VS) fazer a seleção de qual aplicação quero instalar.

Por enquanto tenho um instalador para cada projeto da minha solução, e agora quero centralizar tudo em um instalador só, mas quero que esse instalador tenha a opção de selecionar qual das aplicações quero instalar.
Até o momento estou utilizando um instalador MSI comum, mas que instala todos módulos de uma vez, não tendo a opção de selecionar qual eu quero instalar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) junto com o [ISTool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/istool/)

Nele você vai poder configurar um xml com todas as ações que deseja fazer, até mesmo cascata de installers. Você além de poder montar o seu installer nele, você vai poder colocar para executar outros installers após o seu.