# Como configurar em qual pasta o software deve ser instalado/atualizado?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Segui o exemplo [dessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15267/qual-a-maneira-em-que-aplica%C3%A7%C3%B5es-feitas-em-c-windows-forms-s%C3%A3o-atualizadas-ten) onde é explicado como configurar meu software para ser atualizado automaticamente. Gostaria de saber como faço para alterar em qual pasta essa instalação/atualização deve ocorrer.

Por exemplo, gostaria que o meu programa fosse instalado em `'C:\MeuPrograma'` e que as atualizações ocorressem nesse diretório.

Comment: Eu quero definir a pasta onde o software será instalado. Onde eu defino a pasta de instalação?

Comment: Eric, eu fiz algumas alterações na pergunta para tentar deixá-la mais clara. Se a minha edição não apresentar melhorias, você pode reverte-la por [este link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/64536/revisions)

Comment: Essa resposta que você cita na pergunta não trata de instalação/atualização e sim controle de versão. veja [aqui](http://www.andrealveslima.com.br/blog/index.php/2014/11/27/criando-instaladores-para-aplicativos-net/) e [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43800/instalador-msi-customizando-o-instalador) como criar um instalador.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Clique com o botão direito em seu projeto de instalação no Solution Explorer e escolha "View -> File System".
2. Selecione "Application Folder" na janela que abriu.
3. Na área "Properties Pane" no Visual Studio há um campo chamado "DefaultLocation". Modifique-o para apontar para algum outro lugar diferente de "Program Files".

O valor default para o local de instalação é [ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer][ProductName]. Há algumas variáveis de template que são consultadas quando você compila o programa de setup. [ProgramFilesFolder] é a que irá apontar para a pasta "Program Files" em uma versão em inglês do Windows.

**OBS: esta é uma tradução na íntegra da resposta https://stackoverflow.com/a/3028287/1639385 para esta mesma pergunta em inglês.**